# Token unknown in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

This query is throwing an error on firebird, how to resolve that error?

```
  SELECT EMPNO,SAL 
         FROM EMP E 
         where EMPNO = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO) FROM DEPT D WHERE E.ENAME NOT like (SELECT TOP 1 ENAME 
                                                                              FROM emp E1 
                                                                              WHERE E1.EMPNO=D.DEPTNO))
         OR 1 = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)
                 FROM DEPT D 
                 WHERE E.ENAME like substring('NAME111',1,5))  ORDER BY EMPNO;
```

Here is the error.

> The following error information describes the failure
>
> ODBC Call     = SQLPrepareW()
>
> SQL State     = HY000
>
> Native error  = -104(FFFFFF98)
>
> Error Message = [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
>
> SQL error code = -104
>
> Token unknown - line 1, column 111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***(edit to include alternative, more modern syntax from comments)***

Instead of `SELECT TOP 1 ENAME`, use any of the following:

- `SELECT ENAME ...` [`FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch) (SQL:2008, Firebird 3+)
- `SELECT ENAME ...` [`ROWS 1`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-rows) (non-standard, Firebird 2+)
- `SELECT` [`FIRST 1`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-first-skip) `ENAME ...` (non-standard, effectively Firebird 1.5+)

Also, use

```
substring('NAME111' from 1 for 5)
```

instead of

```
substring('NAME111',1,5)
```

For example, using `FIRST 1`:

```
SELECT EMPNO,SAL
  FROM EMP E
  WHERE EMPNO = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)
                        FROM DEPT D
                        WHERE E.ENAME NOT LIKE (SELECT FIRST 1 ENAME
                                                  FROM emp E1
                                                  WHERE E1.EMPNO=D.DEPTN O))
        OR 1 = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)
                  FROM DEPT D
                  WHERE E.ENAME LIKE substring('NAME111 ' from 1 for 5))
  ORDER BY EMPNO;
```

Comment: @kvk30: "but for SQL is non-empty" makes no sense. Firebird uses SQL as its query language. So anything you write in Firebird **is** "SQL"

Comment: @kvk30 "*I used in SQL*" does not make sense. What else would you be using in Firebird?

Comment: For Firebird 2.0 and up (the OP is on FB3), one should probably use [`ROWS m [TO n]`](http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-select-rows) rather than `FIRST n`.

Comment: @pilcrow For Firebird 3 it would even make more sense to use the SQL standard [`FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/bk01ch09s06.html#rnfb30-dml-offsetfetch)